# How to resolve NullPointerException when updating database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jooq

I'm a jooq neophyte. I'm trying to update a column called account status in my users table from UNLOCKED to LOCKED. I'm using the update query using Jooq's dslContext.

I'm calling this updateAccountStatus method in my Controller. But this method is giving me a NullPointerException.

```
public boolean updateAccountStatus(String userhandle,UsersAccStatus usersAccStatus) { 
try {
dslContext
                    .update(USERS)
                    .set(USERS.ACC_STATUS,UsersAccStatus.LOCKED)
                    .where(USERS.USER_HANDLE.equal(userHandle))
                    .execute();
 }
catch(Exception e) {
// code
}
}
```

I expect the output of this method to update my account_status enum in my database.
Error message :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.core.admin.controller.AdminAccountStatus.execute(AdminAccountStatus.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're showing the entire code relevant to your NPE here? The NPE happens in your `AdminAccountStatus.execute()` method, but you're not callingthat method from your displayed logic.

Answer (score 0):

1) In following line, you are directly using the class `UsersAccStatus`, if you have declared LOCKED as static then it is fine else you have to use the object of class (**U**sersAccStatus) which is **u**sersAccStatus (in small letters)

2) Modify the following code

FROM:

```
.set(USERS.ACC_STATUS,UsersAccStatus.LOCKED)
```

TO:

```
 .set(USERS.ACC_STATUS,usersAccStatus!=null ? null : usersAccStatus.LOCKED)
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Regards,
Anurag

Comment: Hi. I tried what you told. I'm still getting NullPointerException. Do you need any additional info? and I've not declared LOCKED as static..

Comment: Hi, Can you please share the stacktrace of log and highlight exactly on which line are you getting error? As per your comment, it says that the error is at line AdminAccountStatus.java:84 but which line is 84? Kindly copy the line here.